# Receiving delegate messages while Panning/Zooming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a custom UIView which is a delegate of an another class, that constantly sends messages to it (updating the text of an UILabel). This custom view also has an UIScrollView as a subview. The problem is that, while I pan/pinch the scrollview, no delegate messages are received (only after the interaction has finished).

How could I make it receive messages all the time?

---

This is how the other class sends messages to it's delegate:

```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                    target:self
                                  selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];


   - (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
       NSString *label = ...

       if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(updateLabelText:)]) {
           [delegate updateLabelText:label];
           [delegate updateLabelText:label];
       }

       ...

   }
```

Comment: Multithreading, using Grand Central Dispatch or NSOperation. But be sure to do the UI work in the main thread/queue!

Comment: Gesture tracking is done in a special run loop mode.  How/when does your "other class" sends the delegate messages?  If via a timer etc., you may need to add that timer to the appropriate run loop mode. See Apple's NSRunLoop reference & Threading Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIPanGestureRecognizer/UIPinchGestureRecognizer to your UIScrollView and listen delegates method:

```
Regulating Gesture Recognition
– gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:
– gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:
Controlling Simultaneous Gesture Recognition
– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

Comment: I don't want to add any custom UIGestureRecognizer. I want to rely on the scrollview's default scrolling/zooming behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];` solves the problem. Thanks @Jens Kilian!